# Django how to import a file from another file under same folder?

Tags: python, django

This is my Django project structure:

```
project/
    app1/
        static/
        templates/
        utils/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        forms.py
        tasks.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        myfile.py
```

Inside myfile.py, I would like to import the test() function inside the task.py:

```
from . import tasks
tasks.test()
```

The error from my console:

```
$ python myfile.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import tasks
ImportError: cannot import name 'tasks'
```

So how to solve this?

Comment: `from .tasks import test`

Comment: are you importing something from `myfile.py` into your `tasks.py` ?

Comment: no, I just want to call the functions inside the tasks.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use -

```
from .tasks import test
```

or

```
from app1 import tasks
tasks.test()
```

Comment: Here is what I get after `from .tasks import test`. 

`$ python myfile.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tasks import test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.tasks'; '__main__' is not a package`

Comment: try `from app1 import tasks`

Comment: Second one still failed: `$ python myfile.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app1 import tasks
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app1'`

Comment: have you added your `app1` in your installed apps in settings.py ?

Comment: Yes, I do. Its there.